# Getting Keys from a List of Map of Strings

Tags: java, list, hashmap

How to get the keys from a list of Map of Strings?
I have a list of map of strings

```
      List<Map<String, String>> ExcelData = new ArrayList<>();
      Map<String,String> excelMap = new HashMap<>(); 
      excelMap.put("Flower","lily");
      excelMap.put("Fruit","banana");
      ExcelData.add(excelMap);
```

Is there a way to get the keys of this list map in an string array? Thanks

Comment: Questioning design decisions aside (list of maps): `ExcelData.stream().flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())` would grab all of the keys. You can add `#distinct` or use `Collectors.toSet()` if you want unique results.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rogue's comment you can use method reference to make it readable:

```
String[] keys     = ExcelData.stream().map(Map::keySet).flatMap(Set::stream).toArray(String[]::new);
List<String> keyz = ExcelData.stream().map(Map::keySet).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ExcelData.forEach(item -> 
        item.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " -> " + value))
);
```